# Error initializing CBService

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth

I have a previously working iPhone app which uses Bluetooth LE accessories and that I created by modifying a sample source code.

In the myriad of updates to Xcode and IOS, it has stopped building for a reason I can not debug.

It has something to do with initializing a CBService.

Building crashes on the line, saying 'init' is unavailable:

`CBService *gattDBService=[[CBService alloc] init];`

Which in turn points to this line in CBAttribute.h:

`- (instancetype) init NS_UNAVAILABLE;`

I am now using XCode 7.0 and the project is set to deployment target of 7.1.

Why has this project started doing this?
Thanks,
Dale

Further code snippet (re adding services to carousel):

```
-(void)prepareCarouselList
{
    NSArray *allService = [self UUIDArray:[[[CBManager sharedManager] serviceUUIDDict] allKeys]];

    if (proximityServices)
    {
        [proximityServices removeAllObjects];
    }
    if (findMeServices)
    {
        [findMeServices removeAllObjects];

    }

    // Check for sensor hub
    for (CBService *service in [[CBManager sharedManager] foundServices])
    {
        if ([service.UUID isEqual:BAROMETER_SERVICE_UUID])
        {
            [carouselArray addObject:[[[CBManager sharedManager] serviceUUIDDict] valueForKey:[service.UUID.UUIDString lowercaseString]]];
            [carousel_ServiceArray addObject:service];

            isSensorHubFound = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isSensorHubFound)
    {
        for(CBService *service in [[CBManager sharedManager] foundServices])
        {
            if([allService containsObject:service.UUID])
            {
                NSInteger ServiceKeyIndex = [allService indexOfObject:service.UUID];
                CBUUID *keyID = [allService objectAtIndex:ServiceKeyIndex];

                if([service.UUID isEqual:CAPSENSE_SERVICE_UUID] || [service.UUID isEqual:CUSTOM_CAPSENSE_SERVICE_UUID])
                {
                    [self checkCapsenseProfile:service];
                }
                else if(![self checkFindMeProfile:service])
                {

                    if ([service.UUID isEqual:IMMEDIATE_ALERT_SERVICE_UUID])
                    {
                        [findMeServices addObject:service];
                    }
                    [carouselArray addObject:[[[CBManager sharedManager] serviceUUIDDict] valueForKey:[keyID.UUIDString lowercaseString]]];
                    [carousel_ServiceArray addObject:service];

                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"unknown",k_SERVICE_IMAGE_NAME_KEY,[ResourceHandler getServiceNameForUUID:service.UUID],k_SERVICE_NAME_KEY, nil];
                [[[CBManager sharedManager] serviceUUIDDict] setValue:tempDict forKey:[service.UUID.UUIDString lowercaseString]];
                [carouselArray addObject:tempDict];
                [carousel_ServiceArray addObject:service];
            }
        }

    }

    //To add GATT DB item
    [self addGattDBCarouselItem];

    if([carouselArray count])
    {
        [self initCarousel];
    }

}

/*!
 *  @method addGattDBCarouselItem
 *
 *  @discussion Method to add GATTDB carousel item
 *
 */

-(void)addGattDBCarouselItem
{
    [carouselArray insertObject:[[[CBManager sharedManager] serviceUUIDDict] valueForKey:GENERIC_ACCESS_SERVICE_UUID] atIndex:0];
    CBService *gattDBService=[[CBService alloc] init];;    
    [carousel_ServiceArray insertObject:gattDBService atIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CBService doesn't have a init method but CBMutableService does. Try with this:

```
-(void)addGattDBCarouselItem
{
    [carouselArray insertObject:[[[CBManager sharedManager] serviceUUIDDict] valueForKey:GENERIC_ACCESS_SERVICE_UUID] atIndex:0];
    NSString *keyAtIndex = [[[[CBManager sharedManager] serviceUUIDDict] allKeysForObject:carouselArray[0]] objectAtIndex:0];

    CBUUID *keyID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:keyAtIndex];
    CBMutableService *gattDBService=[[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:keyID primary:YES];
    [carousel_ServiceArray insertObject:gattDBService atIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an instance of `CBService` - instances of this object are retrieved from a `CBPeripheral`'s `services` property after service discovery.

If you want to advertise a service as a peripheral then you must instantiate a `CBMutableService` instance.

Comment: That may be the case now, but this code used to build and run, I have it installed and running on both my iPhone and iPad.  I just wanted to change the code a little and I can no longer build it (even the unmodified sample code gets this error). Why?  I have very little experience coding Bluetooth, hence starting with sample.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed how the code tries to use `gattDBService` I could suggest something

Comment: There is a lot of code, however I have shown where it looks like it adds services to a carousel in the question text, let me know if you need more.

Comment: It looks like the code is trying to add the discovered services plus a 'fixed' service to the carousel.  The 'fixed' service is the gattDBService.  In order to keep the array counts correct it then adds a `CBService` instance to the `carousel_ServiceArray`.  You can't do this any more.  I don't know why you want to see the gattDBService in the carousel, but the simplest thing is to probably delete the function `addGattDBCarouselItem`

Comment: I have only been coding Apple devices for a little over a year now and with 3 apps I have, Apple updates broke their code if you updated your operating system. Backwards compatibility does not seem to be a priority to Apple.  In about 30 years of coding Windows programs I can not remember that ever happening (although it likely has without me knowing it since I don't actually have programs I wrote 30 years ago still in use).  I will give that a try and report back, thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't say that they broke their code as such.  It has never been Ok to allocate your own CBPeripheral and the documentation as far back as iOS 5 doesn't list any initialisers, it is just that they corrected the oversight that let you do it.  They have pretty good backward compatibility generally and flag things as "deprecated" for a couple of versions before they are finally removed.  It is true that the mobile app world has a different approach to software dev; an approach that Microsoft are taking now with Azure, O365 and Win10 - continuous updates rather than big bangs every 3 years